# Echo data from php in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a piece of javascript that will display a template of html input fields and image.

I am trying to echo the value of $images->icon in the image src. However the value is not echo out. How should I go about doing it?

```
<img class="gc_thumbnail" src="<?php echo base_url('../contentblock_resources_thumb/'.$images->icon);?>" style="padding:5px; border:1px solid #ddd"/>
```

Javascript template

```
<script type="text/template" id="imageTemplate">
            <div class="row gc_photo" id="gc_photo_{{id}}_{{filename}}"
            style=" border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="gc_thumbnail" src="<?php echo base_url('../contentblock_resources_thumb/'.$images->icon);?>" style="padding:5px; border:1px solid #ddd"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you set the $image as a parameter when you load the view?

Comment: What are expected results and what is current generated output? If value not output what errors does it produce?

Comment: I used $images->? to get values in other parts of the template as well. The current output is '../contentblock_resources_thumb/'. Expected should be ''../contentblock_resources_thumb/abcd.png'

Comment: dump `$images` to be sure you're accessing it correctly.

Comment: please echo $images->icon without tag img ? the name images show right or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/template" id="imageTemplate">
<div class="row gc_photo" id="gc_photo_{{id}}_{{filename}}"
style=" border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
<div class="col-md-2">
 <?php
$image_path = base_url()."contentblock_resources_thumb"; //save folder in varibaale
if ($images->icon=='') //check images exist or not
 {
echo "no image is here";
}
 else
{
 echo " <img  src='$image_path/$images->icon' />";
}
?>
</div>
            </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (put the `$images->icon` outside of `base_url()` function)

```
<img class="gc_thumbnail" src="<?php echo base_url('../contentblock_resources_thumb').'/'.$images->icon;?>" style="padding:5px; border:1px solid #ddd"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just didn't pass the `images` to the view in your controller.
Here's an example of passing values to view:

```
$data['images']->icon = 'abcd.png';
$this->load->view('yourView', $data);
```

Then in view you can simply echo the values:

```
echo $images->icon;
```

Bear in mind that $image will be available in your view. The key-value pairs in the array are automatically converted to variables in the view. In order to pass value to view you can either use an array on an object. For more info see **Adding Dynamic Data to the View** in [Codeigniter user-guide](http://Adding%20Dynamic%20Data%20to%20the%20View)